# I need to zoom on an object upon hover

Tags: three.js, zooming, tween

I want something like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v_4M59Ny93QwT52unfM9N_tfzo3xRAq1/view?usp=share_link

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Three.js JPG Background with Custom Position</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r121/three.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/tween.js/dist/tween.umd.js"></script>

  <!-- Css -->
<style>
  body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    // Initialize Three.js scene
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(window.innerWidth / - 2, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2, window.innerHeight / - 2, 0.1,);
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


    // Load the Main BG texture
    var mainBg = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("http://127.0.0.1:5500/img/main-bg.jpg");

    // Create a full-screen plane to display the texture
    var geometry1 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    var material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: mainBg });
    var plane1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1);
    plane1.position.set(0, 0, 0)
    scene.add(plane1);

    // Create a full-screen plane to display the texture
    var frame1 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("http://127.0.0.1:5500/img/frame1.png");
    var geometry2 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(90, 110);
    var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: frame1 });
    var plane2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, material2);
    plane2.position.set(-190, 130, .1);
    scene.add(plane2);

    // Check if mouse is over the child asset
    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
    var zoomed = false;

    // Mouse move function
    function onMouseMove(event) {
      mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
      mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
      raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
      var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([plane2]);
      if (intersects.length > 0 && !zoomed) {
        zoomed = true;
        camera.position.set(plane2.position.x, plane2.position.y, plane2.position.z);
        camera.lookAt(plane2.position.x, plane2.position.y, plane2.position.z);

      } else if (intersects.length === 0 && zoomed) {
        zoomed = false;
        camera.position.set(0, 0, 5);
        camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
      }
    }
    // Mouse move function calling on moving mouse
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
    window.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
      gsap.to(camera.position, {
        z: 15,
        duration: 15
      });
    })

    // Render loop
    function render() {
      camera.position.z = 5;
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    render();


  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

assets:
[frame1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBvK8.png)

and

[main-bg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwkcz.jpg)

i made frame 1 on the center of the screen by hovering it but cannot make camera to zoom in on it. I tried tween but I think there is something wrong in the basics of my code
Sorry i am new to this and this is my first threejs project

Comment: "*I want something like this:*", the link that you have shared is restricted, please change it to publicly available!

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a `mousemove` event on the canvas and use `event.clientX` or `event.clientY` to read live mouse pointer values. These values can then be used within the the listener to update values of `camera.position.z` to change zoom.

Comment: changing the camera.position.z is having no effect on zoom on the object